# How to update the draw order of a list of controls in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I made a custom WPF editor and I am having trouble getting a list of screen control objects (buttons, text boxes, etc) to be displayed in the correct draw order. Here is a visual of my current setup:

[image]

I have the control object window working just fine and I can see when the list is changed.

My problem is this: Say that I selected object 3 and pressed the up button. The object should move up in the list (which it does!) BUT the draw order stays the same. Meaning that object 3 should draw behind object 2 and its not doing that. I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
    private void MoveUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < controlObjectList.Count; i++)
      {
        if (controlObjectList[i].IsSelected)
        {          
          // Copy the current item
          var selectedItem = controlObjectList[i];
          int newindex = Math.Abs(i - 1);

          // Remove the item
          controlObjectList.RemoveAt(i);

          // Finally add the item at the new index
          controlObjectList.Insert(newindex, selectedItem);
        }
      }
      RefreshControlObjectList(controlObjectList);
    }

    private void MoveDown_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < screenDesigner.m_ParentScreenObject.controlObjects.Count; i++)
      {
        if (controlObjectList[i].IsSelected)
        {
          // Copy the current item
          var selectedItem = controlObjectList[i];
          int newindex = i + 1;

          if(newindex < controlObjectList.Count)
          {
            // Remove the item
            controlObjectList.RemoveAt(i);

            // Finally add the item at the new index
            controlObjectList.Insert(newindex, selectedItem);
          }          
        }
      }
      RefreshControlObjectList(controlObjectList);
    }

    private void RefreshControlObjectList(List<ItemsList> newList)
    {
      newList.Items.Clear();
      foreach (ItemsList il in controlObjectList)
      {
        listObjects.Items.Add(il);
      }
      //I know this is where I should place the logic for the draw order...
    }
    #endregion
  }
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how can I refresh the screen in order to see the correct draw order of my objects? Is it possible? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use the Z-Index property of your elements to solve this.

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg Man, I know and I'm right there with you. But the coleague I'm working with insists (and I cannot stress that enough) that I do it by altering the draw order this way.

Comment: When it has come to "draw order", what i have found is that the draw order is done sequentially by the vertical order in XAML. Meaning if in XAML, Button1 is written a line above Button2, Button2 will be displayed infront of Button1. I had serious requirements for visual ordering as well in a project. The only solution I could come to was Z-Index. From minor research I was unable to find anyway to actually affect the order in which the controls are drawn. I feel like Z-Index is the low hanging fruit. Why does your collegue insist on not using it? is there a good reason?

Comment: To me it would seem excessive to move an object, and then do a complete redraw of the display. Seems like you are wasting resources, and could be solving a problem by causing more. 
Even if you redraw the whole visual tree, you would need extensive testing to make sure things operate as you expect.

Comment: @GingerNinja she wants to make sure that z indexes are set by us only. She's sorta sketchy on  how to manipulate draw orders herself which is why she's having me research this. Many thanks so far all of you are awesome for replying.

Comment: you are also relying on implicit ordering (XAML order, Collection sorting, etc) to draw everything. Just makes me cringe a little for all the "What if" scenarios that can pop up and need to be tested and potentially handled. 
Wanting to have full control over Z-Index, i can see that. What if you were to create a private variable or offload it to the ViewModel in some way, such that it is inaccessible. May violate MVVM slightly, but if seems like a more controllable method that wont bring weird issues.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is exactly what `ZIndex` was designed to do.  What functionality is your colleague  reserving `ZIndex` for, if not this?

Comment: if you store or handle the "Order" in code. you could then write some code behind to handle the ordering in some way. I havent thought this through totally, but i would rather write some code than try to manipulate the Visual systems.

Comment: @GingerNinja you're right. which is why I came here. Seeking guidance.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the "...z-indexes are set by us only". Are you essentially creating a WPF editor? Like replicating Blend or The built in Visual Studio visual editor?

Comment: I am also asking, would be possible/allowed to manipulate the Z-index programmatically, in a way that is private or closed off from the users?

Comment: @GingerNinja its like this: I want to be able to change the logical tree for my objects list at run time. That way I can see the list change as well as the drawn objects.

Comment: Find another job for your co-worker, then use ZIndex and forget about all this.

Comment: Check this out, it may help you to understand Logical and Visual trees better https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21495/Understanding-the-Visual-Tree-and-Logical-Tree-in

Comment: First. I am not confident you can accomplish what you are looking for. As you need to adjust the Visual Tree (not Logical) to see an order change (without Z-Indexes). From a quick look i do not see a quick and simple way to manipulate the Visual Tree programmatically ( i dont even know if it can be done).

Comment: That is why i suggest you write something that manipulates and controls the Z-Index. You would have some algorithm that tracks and sets the Z-Index based on whatever it is you are doing. Maybe your traverse your list and assign a Z-Index equal to their position in the List. You could then multiply other controls by 1000 or something to set them in a group of their own.

Comment: And just a note: You have 4 developers vehemently telling you to manipulate the Z-index. That should hopefully add to the argument that you may be trying something that is far to complex (or not even doable) when there is a viable, existing solution.

Comment: This is equivalent to asking a web developer to manipulate the DOM elements ordering at runtime. You are trying to manipulate a graphic interpretation system that has rules and controls in place for a reason.

Comment: @GingerNinja Thank you all for your input and trust me it was not my intention to confound or annoy anyone with my question. My opinions regarding this issue tips to your side. I will go to colleague and present her with what you have told me. Consider my question answered. Again, sorry if I upset anyone. It was not my intention.

Comment: no worries. you are doing your due diligence in trying to research a task. It just seems that you are trying to enter a building by redesigning the entire structure to surround you, rather than just using the door knob.

Comment: @GingerNinja :p

Comment: Why did I get a down vote? I tried making this question as clear as possible and responded promptly whenever someone wrote me a comment?

Comment: BringForward and SendBackward commands can be accomplished both ways by changing the order of the children or by changing their ZIndex, in fact before introduction of the ZIndex as one of the dependency properties it was only possible by changing the order of the children in the container. Do you have complete code of the sample project by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

`BringForward` and `SendBackward` commands can be accomplished both ways by [1] changing the order of the children or [2] by changing their ZIndex, in fact before the introduction of the ZIndex dependency properties it was only possible by changing the order of the children in the container.

Do you have a complete code sample by any chance? If not here is an example of a sample markup and code which is proving that it is indeed working, but be aware of possible performance impacts of that approach since ZIndex was introduced to fix them.

```
<Canvas Name="container" MouseDown="OnMouseDown">
    <Ellipse Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="10" Fill="Red" Height="100" Width="100"></Ellipse>
    <Ellipse Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="20" Fill="Green" Height="100" Width="100"></Ellipse>
    <Ellipse Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Top="30" Fill="Blue" Height="100" Width="100"></Ellipse>
</Canvas>

private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   var uiElement = e.Source as Ellipse;
   container.Children.Remove(uiElement);
   container.Children.Add(uiElement);
}
```

You would need to figure out if the list of objects you are manipulating by adding and removing the children is indeed the one. It would be helpful to get some context around the variables `controlObjectList` and `listObjects` to see who they belong to.